# A correction factor is necessary for linearized power models fitted using OLS. How does it works for a linearized power mixed effects model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, nonlinear-regression

It is common to fit a (non-linear) power model, e.g. `Y = a*X^b`, through OLS as `log(Y) = log(a) + b*log(x)`.

The prediction on the original scale of Y would be `Y = exp(a + b*log(x)) * Correction factor`.

The correction factor is given as the `exp(var[res]/2)`, where var[res] is the model residual variance.

If one would fit the model `log(Y) = log(a) + b*log(x)` using the lmer R function, let's say, with random intercepts, how it would work regarding prediction? I mean: Is a correction factor necessary to predict Y on its original scale?

I am sorry if this question is silly.

I appreciate the attention. All the best.

Comment: When appropriate, it's attractive instead to use a GLMM with a log link because this directly estimates the conditional expectation and therefore needs no correction factor.  By "appropriate" I mean that the conditional distribution is adequately modeled by the GLMM.  (Using OLS to fit the logarithms is tantamount to assuming the conditional distributions are roughly lognormal and applying the correction factor assumes the conditional distributions are almost exactly lognormal.)

Comment: Nice insight! Thank you very much.